# How to search a term in eloquent relation of a model?

Tags: laravel

There is a Model named Profile that has user relation.

```
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

and the profile table column is:
id | user_id | image | tel

The question is how I can search the name of a user from profile?

```
$term = request()->term;
$profiles = Profile::with('user')->where('name', 'like', '%'.$term.'%')->get();
```

Then I want to show the profiles that their name comes from the search term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `whereHas()` ref link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

```php
 $term = request()->term;
 $profiles = Profile::whereHas('user',function($q) use($term){
       $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
 })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $filterUser = function ($q) use ($term) {
                    $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $term. '%');
                };
  
  $term = request()->term;
  $profiles = Profile::whereHas('user', $filterUser)->with(['user'=> $filterUser])->get();
```

If you want to syntactically optimize the code and want to use this more often then add this method in model

```
public function scopeWithAndWhereHas($query, $relation, $constraint){
    return $query->whereHas($relation, $constraint)
                 ->with([$relation => $constraint]);
}
```

And Usage:

```
 $term = request()->term;
 $profiles = Profile::withAndWhereHas('user', function($q) use ($term){
    $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $term. '%');
})->get();
```

Comment: thank you, for the comprehensive answer, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to scope it on the subquery, something like this:

```
$profiles = Profile::with(['user' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$term.'%');
}])->get();
```